# Power BI - totals per related entity

Tags: powerbi, relational-database, dax

Basically, I’d like to get one entity totals, but calculated for another (but still related/associated!) entity.  Relation type between these entities is many-to-many.
Just to be less abstract, let’s take Trips and Shipments as mentioned entities and Shipments’ weight as a total to be calculated.
Calculating weight totals just per each trip is pretty easy task. Here is a table of Shipments weights:
[image: shipments with their weights]

We place them into some amounts of trucks/trips and get following weight totals per trip:
[image: Shipments' weight total per trips]

But when I try to show SUM of Trip weight totals (figures from 2nd table) per each related Shipment (Column from 1st table), it becomes much harder than I expect.
It should look like:
[image: needed table I can't get in Power BI]

And I can’t get such table within Power BI.

Data model for your reference:
[image: data model]

Seems like SUMMARIZE function is almost fit, but it doesn’t allow me to use a column from another table than initialized in the function:
[image: almost fit but not]

Additional restrictions:

Selections made by user (clicks on cells etc.) should not affect calculation anyhow.

The figures should be able to be used in further calculations, using them as a basis.

Can anyone advise a solution? Or at least proper DAX references to consider? I thought I could find a quick answer in DAX reference guide on my own. However I failed to find a quick answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Version 1

Try the following DAX function as a calculated column inside of your shipments table:

```
TripWeight =
VAR tripID =
    RELATED ( Trips[TripID] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Shipments[ShipmentTaxWeightKG] );
        FILTER ( Shipments; RELATED ( InkTable[TripID] ) = tripID )
    )
```

The first expression `var tripID` is storing the TripID of the current row and the CALCULATE function gets the SUM of all of the weight for all the shipments that belong to the current trip.

## Version 2

You can also create a calculated table using the following DAX and create a relationship between the newly created table and your Trips table and simply display the weight in this table:

```
TripWeight =
GROUPBY (
    Shipments;
    Trips[TripID];
    "Total Weight KG"; SUMX ( CURRENTGROUP (); Shipments[ShipmentTaxWeightKG] )
)
```

## Version 3

Version 1 and 2 are only working if the relationship between lnkTrip and Shipment is a One-to-One relationship. If it is a many-to-one relationship, the following calculated column can be created inside of the Trips table:

```
ShipmentTaxWeightKG by Trip = SUMX(RELATEDTABLE(Shipments); Shipments[ShipmentTaxWeightKG])
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Fabian, thanks for reply!
But it doesn't seem to work ... error is "The column 'Trips[TripID]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context."

Comment: I checked table and column names in your formula and they are pretty correct... however it doesn't want to work.

Comment: You need to create a calulcated column not a calulcated measure. Like described in the entry. + your Trip table in your visualization is called trips. Maybe that's an error as well.

Comment: I tried with column. And it doesn't work. I hosted my test file here:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=87794236296772912151
maybe it will be more convenient for you to try it yourself?

Comment: Do you have a whitespace or anything in your TripID column name? Try creating a calculated column simply for: `RELATED(Trips[TripID])` I have recreated your model and it works. Does your auto-complete work for Trips[TripID]?

Comment: the only one possible typo I noticed in your formula is I(letter i)nkTable. It's l(letter L)nkTable indeed.

Comment: no whitespaces in my TripID column name. I created calculated column (not measure) with simple formula you advised RELATED(Trips[TripID]). And it returns the same error. It doesn't see the table or relation... I don't know for what reason. Names are fully correct

Comment: I just rechecked my solution. The relationship between Shipment and LinkShipment: You have specified it as a many-to-one relationship which makes the solution wrong. Do you have a many-to-one relationship in your data or could you change it to 1:1?

Comment: @OlegDatsenko I have just added a version 3 which would work with a many-to-one relationship. A column that needs to be created inside of the trip table.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's exactly many-to-one relationship. The same ShipmentID can occur few times in lnkTable. And this is only one possible workaround I see to establish many-to-many relationship between Trips and Shipments, only with lnkTable help.

Comment: Check if the version 3 solves your problem. I was thinking that each shipment can only belong to one trip. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: As each shipment can belong to multiple trips and trips can have multiple shipments. What exactly are you looking for? Total Weight by shipment for all the trips that the shipment belongs to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204221/discussion-between-oleg-datsenko-and-fabian-schenker).

Comment: Version 3 is the solution! Thank you so much, Fabian :)